# how to replace "input.getaxis" with a manual code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to replace the "input.getaxis("Horizontal") in unity with a code that i write in order to get the input from a python file.

I tried to understand how it works but unfortunately i didn't understand it well and here is a bit of the code that i did that i want to know if it will do the job or not and how to improve it.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    var h = hh ;//h is the horizontal axis and hh is the previous value
    var v = vv ;//v is the horizontal axis and vv is the previous value
    if (inout == "W" || inout == "w")
    {
        if (v < 1)
        {
            v += 0.01f * wn; //wn is the multiplication for when the user 
                             //presses the key continously {momentum}
        }
        wn += 1;
        sn = 1;//number of presses
    }
    else if (inout == "S" || inout == "s")
    {
        if (v > (-1))
        {
            v -= 0.01f * sn;
        }
        wn = 1;
        sn += 1;
    }
    else if (inout == "A" || inout == "a")
    {
        if (h > (-1))
        {
            h -= 0.01f*an;
        }
        an += 1;
        dn = 1;
    }
    else if (inout == "D" || inout == "d")
    {
        if (h < 1)
        {
            h += 0.01f * dn;
        }
        an = 1;
        dn += 1;
    }
    //Decaying of the momentum
    if (inout != "W" && inout != "S"&& inout != "w" && inout != "s")
    {
        if (v > 0)
        {
            if (wn>1)
            {
                wn--;
            }
            v -= 0.01f * wn;
        }
        else if (v < 0)
        {
            if (sn>1)
            {
                sn--;
            }
            v += 0.01f * sn;
        }
    }
    else if (inout != "A" && inout != "D"&& inout != "a" && inout != "d")
    {
        if (h > 0)
        {
            if (dn>1)
            {
                dn--;
            }
            h -= 0.01f * dn;
        }
        else if (h < 0)
        {
            if (an>1)
            {
                an--;
            }
            h += 0.01f * an;
        }
    }
    hh = h;
    vv = v;
```

**in a nutshell all this code does is when the python file sends input "W" for example it it increases the value of the vertical axis by (0.01) multiplied by the number of presses on the w key this gives us chance to build momentum as when the user presses it once it goes slowly up then when pressing it continuously it begins to build up and go up more rapidly.
the decaying part is for when the user releases the key we want to release all the momentum that we built so it undoes everything.**

- all i want is someone who can describe how the getaxis work
- to know if this code will work and how to modify it to make it better
  or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: you should at least use a frame independent value by doing e.g. `0.01f * Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a keyboard, Unity's `GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` and `GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`  return -1, 0 or 1 for each axis. The values of `GetAxis("Horizontal")`and `GetAxis("Vertical")` are smoothed by an algorithm using those raw inputs.

Here is one way you could approximate Unity's smoothing algorithm in a way that smooths raw -1, 0, or 1 values calculated from your keyboard controller's input:

```
private float slidingH;
private float slidingV;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float h = 0f;
    float v = 0f;
    Vector2 smoothedInput;

    if (inout.ToLower() == "w") 
    {
        v = 1f;
    }
    else if (inout.ToLower() == "s")
    {
        v = -1f;
    }
    else if (inout.ToLower() == "a")
    {
        h = -1f;
    }
    else if (inout.ToLower() == "d")
    {
        h = 1f;
    }

    smoothedInput = SmoothInput(h,v);

    float smoothedH = smoothedInput.x;
    float smoothedV = smoothedInput.y;

}


private Vector2 SmoothInput(float targetH, float targetV)
{
    float sensitivity = 3f;
    float deadZone = 0.001f;

    slidingH = Mathf.MoveTowards(slidingH,
                  targetH, sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);

    slidingV = Mathf.MoveTowards(slidingV ,
                  targetV, sensitivity * Time.deltaTime);

    return new Vector2(
           (Mathf.Abs(slidingH) < deadZone) ? 0f : slidingH ,
           (Mathf.Abs(slidingV) < deadZone) ? 0f : slidingV );
}
.
```

This is a modified version of the code in [this answer by fafase](http://answers.unity.com/answers/958701/view.html) on the Unity QA site.

As a sidenote, depending on your needs you may want to add a way to send multiple simultaneous pressed keys from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

## Separate the concerns between accepting input and moving the object

If you separate your tasks, you will be able to replace your input with whatever mechanism you want. You can test with `Input.GetAxis` and then switch the input to Python as long as the outputs are the same.

`FixedUpdate` is used by Unity for physics calculations. Accept input in your `Update` method instead, then apply your changes to physics enabled objects in `FixedUpdate`.

Most of what you are doing is achieved by the built-in [Unity Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html) engine. Utilize the `Rigidbody` component for this instead of directly setting `Transform`. You can still deteriorate based on non-input inside of `FixedUpdate` and apply all your changes at once and let the physics engine do the actual calculations.

#### Notes on your questions at the bottom of your question

- [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) returns a `float` ranging from -1 to 1
- Once you separate your two tasks, your code should flow better naturally
- Since `Input.GetAxis` outputs a range from -1 to 1 based on how far a controller stick is from the center, 0.01 is a minuscule measurement. You would have to press a key 100 times to get the same output as pressing a controller stick all the way to one side. I would use values closer to -1 and 1, and multiply by some value set in the Inspector to produce a good feel
- I don't have an answer for how to get input from Python to Unity directly. That will likely depend on if it is a networked solution or on the same computer. Output from a networked solution will not matter how it was produced regardless

Comment: Asker isn't moving anything in their code. Their code as shown is all an attempt at input smoothing, not any kind of calculation of a physical body's momentum.

Comment: They also did not finish the `FixedUpdate` method. I assumed an object was going to be moving since there is no other code like `Update` explicitly stated.